# Rails: Show Followers/Following

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, relationship

I am currently having problems with this section of the Rails Tutorial: Showing the Followers/Following. The problem that is identified is:

```
Missing partial users/user with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:  * "/Users/--/rails/--/app/views"
```

Extracted source (around line #3):

```
<% unless @users.empty? %>
 <ul class="users">
  <%= render @users %>
 </ul>
 <%= will_paginate @users %>
<% end %>
```

**users controller**

```
def following
   @title = "Following"
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @users = @user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page])
   render 'show_follow'
end

def followers
   @title = "Followers"
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
   render 'show_follow'
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
     member do
       get :following, :followers
     end
end
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Looks like your `user` partial is in the wrong directory or missing. It's expected to be in `app/users/_user.html.erb`

Comment: @osahyoun In fact, it should be in `app/views/users/_user.html.erb`.

Comment: whoops. Thanks for catching that. +1

Answer (score 0):

copy `users/index.html.erb` which is meant to show 'all users' and paste code in create named `users/_user.html.erb`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else stumbles across this question, there's a section of the book well before the follower/following features (which is around Listing 12.24) that addresses a _user.html.erb partial (See Ruby on Rails Tutorial, Listing 9.46 onward). It takes a portion of the app/views/users/index.html.erb and places in the following, which is vital for the follower/following feature to work correctly:

```
app/views/users/_user.html.erb
<li>
 <%= gravatar_for user, size: 50 %>
 <%= link_to user.name, user %>
 <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
   | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                 data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
 <% end %>
</li>
```

Make sure you adjust your app/views/users/index.html.erb to remove the code and replace it with use of rendering the partial.